# How to keep the width of 4 items to always fill the UIView parent container

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have 4 items in a UIView which should always fill the UIView for all Screen sizes. It doesn't matter which auto layout constraints I apply, they won't fill the view equally (each item won't have the same width)

[Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3jgezeva3kvt822/Screenshot%202014-10-28%2010.00.29.png?dl=0) for a picture for 5.5 inches iPhones.

And [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kw1id3pcvmlz9jx/Screenshot%202014-10-28%2010.01.41.png?dl=0) for 4 inch iPhones.

As you can see, the last icon is not in the view anymore in the 4 inch screen.

How can I apply a flexible, stretchable layout in Interface Builder? Do I have to make a custom View and modify the constraints in code?

Comment: In your case it doesn't look its possible by manually setting the resizing option, best way is to programmatically add the buttons considering the width, and one more thing try use same dimension use Centre fill property instead of Scale to Fill. Make the buttons bigger than max size of image say if you have max size is 80, keep the width and height to 85, so all fit inside and with centre fill property all will be centre aligned and proper.

Comment: thanks @iphonic I used a little bit of both (interface builder and code) to get the results I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it in code. I applied width constraints and changed the sizes in `viewDidLoad()`. For X-Positioning I just aligned one item next to the other (horizontal spacing).